# Is there a way to tell Android Studio 3.0.1 to highlight exception throwers?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to tell Android Studio 3.0.1 to highlight every method in a code that can throw an exception? To identify where to use "try - catch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java methods that throw an exception that has to be caught (put inside try/catch block), the code will not compile until you do, so you will get a red line / compilation error if you don't.

Those are called checked exceptions which are exceptions that has to be caught, like IO.

Other exceptions, which are not checked, or run time exceptions, normally shouldn't not be handled by a try/catch, but you need to guard for them or fix them.

For example, instead of catching `NullPointerException`, you should check for `null` if the instance can be `null`.

Comment: Let's take for example "SharedPreferences.getInt(String key, int defValue)". It throws  ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int. If I do not put it inside a try/catch block I do not get a red line/compilation error (Android Studio is simply not seeing it as an compilation error). I would like to use try/ catch because in "catch" I want to create logs (text files) with possible errors from users. So, Is there a way to tell Android Studio 3.0.1 to highlight every method in a code that can throw an exception?

Comment: ClassCastException  is the kind of exception you should fix, not "catch", make sure that when you put preference of certain type, that you get it as the same type. Because simply you cannot recover from an exception like that, what value will you use instead of the one you couldn't cast, it will be incorrect. Use the run time crashes to catch those cases and fix them while developing

Comment: Thank you. You are right about that. That is the good practice. Anyway, is it possible to tell Android Studio 3.0.1 to highlight every method in a code that can throw an exception? That is a YES on No question. :)

Comment: No, because virtually, all methods can throw "runtime" exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

In the current Android Studio 4, when standing on the throw, the throwing lines are highlighted.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will let you choose an existing one.

Comment: Use sonal lint plugin